# Model a Hungarian algorithm problem to standard linear programming

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming

I have solved this problem with the Hungarian algorithm and my total cost at the end gives the solution of 25.
But my question is, is it possible to pass this table to standard linear programming and solve that problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, let nonnegative decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether worker $i$ is assigned to job $j$. You will have one $\le 1$ constraint for each $i$ and one $=1$ constraint for each $j$. You can either fix $x_{3,3}=0$ or just omit it everywhere. The solution will automatically be integer-valued.

Comment: you mean for example x11+x12+x13 +x14<=1 , and x11+x21+x31+x41+x51 = 1 ?

Comment: Yes, just like that.